# Get the controller in a view

Tags: ember.js

I use the lastest emberjs 1.0 pre4.

In App.FormController, I insert a childView to a containerView:

```
containerView.get('childViews').pushObject(
    App.FieldData4MultipleChoiceView.create()
);
```

In this childView, I try to print "me.get('controller')":

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    var me = this;
    $(".fieldset.group").on("click", ".fieldChoice img", function(e){
        var controller = me.get('controller');
        console.log(controller); // line A
    });
}
```

Question 1: 
Why "line A" return an instance of App.ApplicationController class but not App.FormController?

Question 2: 
How can I get single instance of App.FormController in any other view (not just the view under App.FormController)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: Why "line A" return an instance of App.ApplicationController class but not App.FormController?

Your example says "In App.FormController, I insert a childView to a containerView" but it's not clear how that containerView came to exist or what it's context is. That childView will inherit the context of it's parent, so my guess is that containerView itself does not have `App.FormController` as it's controller.

> Question 2: How can I get single instance of App.FormController in any other view (not just the view under App.FormController)?

You can't, at least not without really hacking ember's internal APIs. This is by design. Each view should be really lightweight and depend only on it's corresponding controller. That controller can bind to App.FormController or one of it's properties, but the view does not need to be aware.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Why "line A" return an instance of
>   App.ApplicationController class but not App.FormController?

I don't quite understand why the context is not being passed into the view, but you can specify the controller yourself by passing it through when you instantiate the view:

```
App.FieldData4MultipleChoiceView.create({ controller: this.get('formController'); });
```

> Question 2: How can I get single instance of App.FormController in any
>   other view (not just the view under App.FormController)?

You need to pass through the controller if you're doing it the way you're doing it. You could use `{{render "my"}}` in your Handlebars, which will automatically attach `MyView` and `MyController`. However, if you're not doing it this way then you can pass controllers in using `setupController`:

```
var MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('formController', this.controllerFor('form'));
    }
});
```

Now you'll have access to `this.get('formController')` from within the `MyController` instance.

*In EMBER 1.0.0-PRE.5 we won't have `this.controllerFor` any more, but instead we'll use the `needs` to specify the required controllers in any given controller.*